# Problem on Contraction mapping

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Here is my question :

Define $T :C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1] $ by $T(x)(t) = 1+\int_0 ^t
x(s)ds$. Where the metric in $C[0,1]$ is defined as $d(f,g) = max_{x \in[0.1]}|f(x) - g(x)|$.

a) Is T a contraction?

b) Now we change the space to $C[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ . Is T a contraction?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should attempt to say what you've done and where you are stuck so that we can provide the best assistance.

Answer (score 2):

for the first one answer is no. note that for $f=1$ we have $T(f)=1+t$ and for $g=0, T(g)=1$ so $d(f,g)=1=d(T(f),T(g))$

for the second one yes.
\begin{align}
d(T(f),T(g))&=max_{x \in[0.1]}|1+\int_0 ^t
f(s)ds- (1+\int_0 ^t
g(s)ds)|\\
 & =max_{x \in[0.1]}|\int_0 ^t
f(s)ds- 
g(s)ds)| \\ 
 & \leq \frac{1}{2}max_{x \in[0.1]}|f(x)-g(x)| \\
 & =\frac{1}{2}d(f,g)
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

$d(Tx(t),Ty(t))=\max_{t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]}|T(x(t)-Ty(t)|=\max_{t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]}|\int _0^t(x(s)-y(s)) ds|\leq$

$ \max_{t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]}(\max_{s\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]} |x(s)-y(s)|)\int _0 ^tds=(\max_{s\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]} |x(s)-y(s)|)\max_{t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]}t$

$\leq \frac{1}{2}(\max_{s\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]} |x(s)-y(s)|)<\max_{s\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]} |x(s)-y(s)|=\max_{t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]} |x(t)-y(t)|$

$=d(x(t),y(t))$

Comment: There are two mistakes here: the first one is that you do not exhibit a constant making $T$ a contraction, you only show that it is a Lipschitz map with Lipschitz constant $1$; the second one is that you mix the two questions asked by the OP in a single answer (you start with $[0,1]$ and then miraculously you continue with $[0, \dfrac 1 2]$.

Comment: @AlexM.;note that a map $T$ is said to be a contraction if $d(Tx,Ty)<d(x,y)$ said to be a shrinking map if $d(Tx,Ty)\leq \alpha d(x,y)$ for some $0<\alpha<1$

Comment: @Amartya [Wikipedia disagrees with your terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) (as do I).

Comment: Well consult Munkres Topology section:Compactness

Comment: @Amartya I just consulted Munkres, and you've got it backwards.  If $d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$ he calls $f$ a *shrinking map* and if $d(f(x),f(x)) \leq \alpha \, d(x,y)$ for some $\alpha < 1$ then $f$ is a *contraction*.  See pp. 181-182 of the 2nd edition.

Comment: @Amartya: Man, you are really difficult to deal with, always ready to contradict those who know more than you... Are you here to learn, or to fight us? If you're about fighting, we are not interested, thank you. The definition that you give above corresponds to "short maps" (or "non-expanding maps"); for contractions you need to find a $C \in [0, 1)$ such that $d(Tx, Ty) \le C d(x,y) \ \forall x, y$.